# Add Facebook application friend invite using asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook

I want to add code for a friend invite in my Facebook application using asp.net

```
<p>Invite a friend to use this application...
<fb:request-form action="default2.aspx" method="POST" invite="true"
type="Ankush" content="You have been invited to the Test Example application.
<% = Server.HtmlEncode("<fb:req-choice url=""http://apps.facebook.com/ankushgupta/default2.aspx"" label=""OK"" />")  %>  " >
<fb:friend-selector showborder="false" actiontext="Invite your friends to use this application." />
<fb:request-form-submit />
</fb:request-form>
</p>
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

On June 6 2012, FBML will be deprecated.

Consider looking into the Requests Dialog http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/